# What can cause a ssh connection to slow down over time?

Tags: ssh, performance, lag

At work, I regularly connect to one of our web servers via SSH. I usually keep the connection open all day long, as I frequently need it. I mainly edit some text files via `vim`. After about 6 hours, the connection seems to become slower (key inputs take longer and longer to process, to the point where input lag can get into the range of 20 seconds). Once I start noticing the lag to creep in, it usually doesn't take long for it to get really bad.

Disconnecting and re-connecting with about 5 minutes in between does *not* solve the issue; the new connection will be as slow as the previous one from the beginning. However, the following day, my fresh session will be fast again, but also slow down again after about 6 hours.

I'm connecting using `ssh` from a Debian bullseye client to a Debian jessie server. According to `top`, the server has plenty of resources left.

- What could be the cause of this consistent slow-down and what could I do to prevent it?

Comment: Are you certain it's not a consequence of server load increasing later in the day?

Comment: @CliffArmstrong that was my first thought, hence I checked with `top` on the server - everything seems fine; CPU load is about 1% and there is more than 1 GB of RAM left.

Comment: The SSH slowdown is a symptom of another problem. Maybe a failing hard disk. Don't just use top, look at vmstat and network congestion.

Comment: If you one day might not connect at all until "after about 6 hours", then you could tell if the problem is "over time" or simply "around certain time". I suspect the latter. What do you know about the server? If it's virtual and the host is overloaded, you may not be able to diagnose the situation from within the guest. Are you responsible for the server or the network at your workplace? If not, contact people who are.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments so far. You are right. I will investigate the server in more detail and see if I can find anything suspicious.

Comment: When this happened to me, inevitably this was due to my router. Restarting my router fixed the ssh slowness even between computers on the same network.